# When To Use Different Image Files On The Same Page

Tags: html, image, performance

Say I have two of the same image being displayed on a page, but at different sizes. I know that having an image already the correct size that it is to be displayed increases performance (especially on mobile devices), but I also know that using the same `src` creates only one trip to download the image.

So my question is, which of these two options would generally provide the best performance considering all the possible variables (browser, device, computing power, internet speed, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many variables for someone to answer the question definitively.  For example, for a newer device, which will have a faster graphics processor, on a slow network, one file might be best because it can resize it quickly.  So you have connection speed, graphics processing speed, number of images, composition of images, and size of images as factors that will impact what is best.

Comment: That's a way I didn't think about it. And I have to disagree with the vote to close "because it's opinion based", as this is definitely a testable thing with an correct answer, but without me giving way more information, this is definitely able enough to get me onto the right track. Thanks!

Comment: The browser that is being used (_if_ a browser is being used) to view the images might also be a significant factor.  I would just go with my gut and if you get complaints about it being slowish then try to gather environment information from the complaining users.  Another factor--is it going to be the same images (such as a logo or icon) over and over again?  If yes, then send separate images and the browser will use the cached copy and the download speed is irrelevant after the first view.

Comment: I also think this is a legit question.  You might reword it as, "What factors do I need to consider..." instead of asking which is best...